# `ip route add` is not reflected in `ip route show`

Tags: routing

I'm trying to add a route to use a vpn connection with `ip route add ${HOST_IP} dev ${MY_VPN_INTERFACE}`, yet after having done so and observing an exit code of 0, `ip route show` doesn't list `${HOST_IP}`.

If instead of using my vpn interface for the device I use `lo`, the change *is* reflected in the output of `ip route show`. Example:

```bsh
sudo ip route add 128.34.6.55 dev lo
ip route show | grep 128.34.6.55
# => 128.34.6.55 dev lo scope link
```

What's going on here?

*I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. My `${MY_VPN_INTERFACE}` is a vpn connection provided by Cisco AnyConnection client.*

Comment: The change is reflected in the output of `ip route show`… could you be precise about this change ? How it differs from what is expected (something starting from $IP_HOST I suppose.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer thanks for asking. I mean that grepping `ip route show` produces some outout, for example `ip route show | grep 128.216.18.19` produces `128.216.18.19 dev lo scope link`. If my attempt to add a route is _not_ reflected in `ip route show`, then grepping it for my host ip produces empty output.

Comment: Well, the problem was the use of cisco anyconnect. As long as it was running, it was overwriting any routing rules that I wrote which had to do with the vpn interface. (Ooh, those asynchronous troubleshooting issues.) The solution was to use openconnect and _not_ anyconnect.